# flask-admin "AdminIndexView" not working to restrict the /admin page

Tags: flask, flask-admin

this is my first question in stackoverflow.

i need to change flask_admin's default page but it's not working, i want to make it inaccessible for non-admin users...

**admin file:**

```
from flask import redirect, url_for
from flask_admin import AdminIndexView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms.fields import FileField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

from . import adm, db
from .models import User, Product


def configure():
    adm.index_view = IndexAdmin()

    adm.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
    adm.add_view(ProductsAdmin(Product, db.session))


class IndexAdmin(AdminIndexView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for("views.home_page"))


class UserAdmin(ModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ["created_date", "updated_date", "products", "adresses"]
    column_exclude_list = ["password", "phone", "money"]
    column_searchable_list = ["email"]

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for("admin.index"))


class ProductsAdmin(ModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ["created_date", "updated_date", "user_products"]
    column_exclude_list = ["image"]

    column_type_formatters = {"image": FileField(label="Image", validators=[DataRequired()])}

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for("admin.index"))
```

I tried to do this to put the page restrict, but this isn't working...

```
class IndexAdmin(AdminIndexView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for("views.home_page"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is the gap, but the official docs do not suggest setting this as you are with `adm.index_view =`. Instead https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#default-view suggests:

```py
admin = Admin(index_view=MyHomeView())
```

So, one possibility is that the init process for Admin() does something with the index_view that doesn't happen when you set it directly.

The docs (https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#flask_admin.base.Admin.init_app) also indicate that you can delay this by using `init_app`, which is the way I've used it before. Something like:

```py
admin.init_app(app, index_view= MyHomeView())
```

Comment: Thank you man, I just needed to do this admin.init_app(app, index_view= MyHomeView()) in init_app!

Comment: Good to hear! It's customary here to click the check-mark next to an answer that solves the problem. (This helps other answerers see that your question is solved, and other people with the same question identify a good answer more quickly.)